# Protocol Buffers packages issue

Tags: maven, protocol-buffers

I am new to Protocol Buffers, and I have just added the library / build requirements for my `Maven` project. I now have a `.proto` file in my source repository that has little to nothing in it:

```
package com.christopher.kade;
option java_package= "protocol";

message Protocol {
    required int32 id = 1;
    required string name = 2;
}
```

But I've found myself facing a problem when it comes to `packages`, the following file creates a `protocol` package in my `com.christopher.kade` one and I get an error message stating that:

> Package name 'protocol' does not correspond to the file path 'com.christopher.kade.protocol'.

What is the good approach in order to generate my class in my current package? Therefore I would have:

```
com.christopher.kade
|- client.proto
|- MyGeneratedClass.java
|- MyClass.java
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is in this line

> option java_package= "protocol";

Change it to

> option java_package= "com.christopher.kade";

and you are good!